# Was Black Thirteen responsible for 9/11?

Tags: the-dark-tower

During the course of [*The Dark Tower VI: Song of Susannah*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dark_Tower_VI:_Song_of_Susannah) Jake and Pere Callahan, in 1999 Keystone World, need to get rid of Black Thirteen before going to rescue Susannah from the Dixie Pig. In order to put it somewhere safe they choose no other place than a public safety locker right under the World Trade Center.

Now it has been mentioned often enough that Black Thirteen is the most powerful *and* most dangerous part of Maerlyn's Rainbow and together with the rest of the Rainbow is somehow cursed and seems to be driven by an inherently evil or destructive conciousness. It has repeatedly tried to harm the ka-tet in order get free, primarily by hypnotizing them into murder and suicide.

Seeing how close to the [9/11 terror attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/September_11_attacks) the ka-tet brings Black Thirteen right to the World Trade Center and we never hear about it again (and provided Keystone World is supposed to be our very own universe), this makes me wonder if we're supposed to believe that it had anything to do with the 9/11 attacks. But **is there anything further, either in additional textual hints or more substantial extended material, to suggest that Black Thirteen had a hand in 9/11**, be it by its own direct intention or simply by its cursed presence?

Comment: As an alternate reading, my first impression was that fate decided to put the damned thing in a place it might be destroyed or buried forever.

Comment: @Radhil Maybe you can flesh that out into an answer if substantiated further?